# Can I pass Httpserveltrequest/response object to run() method using Class variables?

Tags: java, multithreading, servlets, httprequest

I make an ajax call and hit the following code in java class

```
if("callfirstPageStoredProcedure".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getParameter("mode"))) {
    synchronized(this) {
        pb = new PayrollBean(request, response, logininfo, request.getParameter("mode"));
        pb.startThread();
    }
}
```

so In class `payrollBean` with the help of this new constructor I set requet and response arguments as Global variables.

Then in run() method I try to access those Parameters but it seems they are not available here and `nullPointerexception` is thrown.

**Constructor** :

```
public PayrollBean(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, LoginInfo loginInfo, String methodToCall){
    this.request      = request;
    this.response     = response;
    this.loginInfo    = loginInfo;
    this.methodToCall = methodToCall;
}
```

**Start method Calling :**

```
public void startThread(){
    payrollThread=new Thread(this);
    payrollThread.start();
    System.err.println("The payrollThread is started Now!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
}
```

Run method:

```
public void run(){
    int InCatch = 0;
    try {
        if("callfirstPageStoredProcedure".equalsIgnoreCase(methodToCall)) {
            callfirstPageStoredProcedure(request, response, loginInfo);
        }
    }
```

Any get any idea what am I be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Each request object is valid only within the scope of a servlet’s
>   service method, or within the scope of a filter’s doFilter method

Therefore, you shouldn't save any reference to `HttpServletRequest` and `HttpServletResponse` for use in another thread. You can not access request parameters once the original request has finished. And your `Thread` sometimes will be executed before the request has finished and sometimes later.

Instead you should copy the information you need from the original request for later processing.

Extract from [Java Servlet Specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/servlet-3.0-fr-oth-JSpec/):

> *3.11 Lifetime of the Request Object*
>
> **Each request object is valid only within the scope of a servlet’s service method, or within the scope of a filter’s doFilter method**,
>   unless the asynchronous processing is enabled for the component and
>   the startAsync method is invoked on the request object. In the case
>   where asynchronous processing occurs, the request object remains valid
>   until complete is invoked on the AsyncContext. **Containers commonly
>   recycle request objects in order to avoid the performance overhead of
>   request object creation.** The developer must be aware that
>   maintaining references to request objects for which startAsync has not
>   been called outside the scope described above is not recommended as it
>   may have indeterminate results.